# Measuring the length of an array, not characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, string-length

I have one problem regarding the `length` function. The problem is that when more than one entries come in the variable, it calculates the length perfectly but for a single entry, it starts to measure the number of characters instead of the amount of elements in the array. I want the alert to show 1 because there is one entry: `finance consultant`, but it's showing 18.

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'#FFF' });
var tableView1=Titanium.UI.createTableView(); 
var Row = [];
Titanium.Yahoo.yql(
  'select * from html where url="http://..." '
  + 'and xpath="//tbody/tr/td/a/font" limit 25', 
  function(e) {
    results = e.data.font;
    results = results.content;
    alert(results.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var rss = results[i];
      var rssRow = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({ ... });
      var titleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({ ... });
      rssRow.add(titleLabel);
      Row.push(rssRow);
    };

    tableView1.setData(Row);
  });

win.add(tableView1);
win.open();
```

Comment: anyway using `for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {` is bad practice, because `for` have to determine array length in every passage through the loop. More efficient would be `for (var i = 0, max = results.length; i < max; i++) {`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
results = results.content;
if (typeof results === 'string')
  results = [results];
alert(results.length);
```

So now you've forced a `result` that is a string to be an array of one string. The rest of your code should work unmodified.

Comment: Hi Thanks for help.I cant explain to you how much difficult problem you have solved for me

Answer (score 2):

In the line of **slashingweapon** answer, but simplified, why don't you just do this:

```
var length = 0;

if(typeof results === "string") {
    length = 1;
} else {
    length = results.length;
}

alert(length);
```

It's simpler and cleaner.